# proving a logical equivalence

Tags: logic

I have to prove that $P \land Q \rightarrow \neg R \equiv \neg(P \land Q \land R)$.

So far I've used the law of implies to make it $(\neg P ∧ \neg Q) \lor \neg R$,
then De Morgan's law to make it $\neg(P \land Q \land R)$.

Is this correct?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Why the negation sign to the far right of the formula?

Comment: Having said that, and assuming that the negation sign prefixes the RHS formula, as you said you have to apply De Morgan to it to get $(¬ P \lor ¬ Q \lor ¬R)$. For the LHS formula, use [Material Implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)).